# How to create add an unordered list with li to a div using javascript with form validation

Tags: javascript, html

I am validating a login form and for each error with the form validation (e.g. incorrect username or email format), I want to display an unordered list containing the errors. I know how to validate the input etc. but I can't figure out how to add in an unordered list in my if statements. I know these if statements may be inefficient for validation and incorporating an unordered list will recreate an unordered list in each if statement. but I am required to learn JavaScript in 3 weeks. Here is my HTML code:

```js
let fullName = document.getElementById("fullName");
let formErrors = document.getElementById("formErrors");
let email = document.getElementById("email");
let emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}$/
let password = document.getElementById("password");
let passwordConfirm = document.getElementById("passwordConfirm");
let submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");

function checkForm() {
  // TODO: Perform input validation 
  if (fullName.value < 1) {
    formErrors.style.display = "block";
    formErrors.innerHTML = "Missing full name";
  };
  if (email != emailRegex) {
    formErrors.style.display = "block";
    formErrors.innerHTML = "Missing email";
  }
  if (password.value < 10 || password.value > 20) {
    formErrors.style.display = "block";
    formErrors.innerHTML = "Password must be between 10 and 20 characters."
  }
}

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  checkForm();

  // Prevent default form action. DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<h1>User Registration</h1>
<form>
  <label for="fullName">Full Name</label> <br>
  <input type="text" id="fullName" class="defaulx"> <br>
  <label for="email">Email</label> <br>
  <input type="email" id="email" class="defaulx"> <br>
  <label for="password">Password</label> <br>
  <input type="password" id="password" class="defaulx"> <br>
  <label for="passwordConfirm">Confirm Password</label> <br>
  <input type="password" id="passwordConfirm" class="defaulx"> <br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Register">
</form>
<div id="formErrors" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know how to validate and do the conditions, I am just adding only a fragment to support your code. Hopes this will help you to create a list of errors.

```js
function checkForm() {
   // TODO: Perform input validation
   var ul = document.createElement('UL');
   if (true) {
      var li = document.createElement('LI');
      li.innerHTML = "Missing full name";
      ul.appendChild(li);
   };
   if (true) {
      var li = document.createElement('LI');
      li.innerHTML = "Missing email";
      ul.appendChild(li);
   }
   if (true) {
      var li = document.createElement('LI');
      li.innerHTML = "Password must be between 10 and 20 characters."
      ul.appendChild(li);
   }
   document.getElementById('formErrors').appendChild(ul);
}

checkForm();
```

```html
<div id="formErrors"></div>
```

What the code does is

```
var ul = document.createElement('UL');
```

this will create a `<ul></ul>` element.

on each if

```
var li = document.createElement('LI');
```

this will create a `<li></li>` element

```
li.innerHTML = "Missing email";
```

this will set the html value to it.

```
ul.appendChild(li);
```

this will append the li to the ul providing `<ul><li></li></ul>`

Comment: Maybe you could improve the answer as OP has a container already: #formErrors. Or maybe add the ID to your UL you're building and OP can style it to show up when there are errors.

Comment: Updated it to the comment, all I ment to provide is just the fragment that will help the op learn the concept. I know this question is based on some activity which was provided to op by someone.

Comment: Thank you, I read your code and got it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach:

```js
let fullName = document.getElementById("fullName");
let formErrors = document.getElementById("formErrors");
let email = document.getElementById("email");
let emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}$/
let password = document.getElementById("password");
let passwordConfirm = document.getElementById("passwordConfirm");
let submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");

function checkForm() {
   // TODO: Perform input validation 
   const errors = []
   if (fullName.value < 1) {
      errors.push("Missing full name");
   }
   if (!emailRegex.test(email.value)){ // note this change 
      errors.push("Missing email");
   }
   if (password.value < 10 || password.value > 20) {
      errors.push("Password must be between 10 and 20 characters.");
   }
   let ul = document.createElement("ul");
   errors.forEach(error => {
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = error;
        ul.appendChild(li);
   });
   formErrors.innerHTML = ""; // clear what had been displayed
   formErrors.appendChild(ul);
}

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
   checkForm();

   // Prevent default form action. DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>User Registration</title>
   <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="register.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
   <h1>User Registration</h1>
   <form>
      <label for="fullName">Full Name</label> <br>
      <input type="text" id="fullName" class="defaulx"> <br>
      <label for="email">Email</label> <br>
      <input type="email" id="email" class="defaulx"> <br>
      <label for="password">Password</label> <br>
      <input type="password" id="password" class="defaulx"> <br>
      <label for="passwordConfirm">Confirm Password</label> <br>
      <input type="password" id="passwordConfirm" class="defaulx"> <br>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Register">
   </form>
   <div id="formErrors"></div>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```